# Oracle.DataAccess.dll как ищет другие необходимые dll

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle

Я в своем приложении на C# использую библиотеку Oracle.DataAccess.dll для работы с БД Oracle. Эта библиотека и другие необходимые ей компоненты лежат в папке с программой. На компьютере, где не стоит клиент Oracle, программа работает нормально, а где стоит клиент, там выходит ошибка.

[image: ошибка]

Версии установленного клиента и библиотек, используемых в программе, не совпадают. Почему DataAccess ищет нужные ей dll не в текущем каталоге?

Установка более нового клиента невозможна: не будет работать старая корпоративная программа.

Comment: Попробуйте ловить и обрабатывать `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`.

Comment: Можете пример написать? А то я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это связано с несоответствием версий платформы, клиента оракла и подключенной библиотеки.

- убедитесь, что в референсах, флаг "конкретная версия", для Oracle.DataAccess проставлен в false
- соберите приложение под x86 либо x64 платформы

Одна из конфигураций заработает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]